# Charge inducing electric field or electromagnetic fields?

Tags: electromagnetism, particle-physics

I am thinking the therminology here which is about Gas Electron Multipliers (GEM). There is a continuous flow of the fill gas which is ionized so no particles created/destroyed:

#1

> By Gauss's law, the distribution of electric charge results in the electromagnetic fields in a volume and is proportional to the change inside.

#2

> By Gauss's law, the distribution of electric charge results in the electric field in a volume and is proportional to the change inside.

### Proposal after JCP's answer

#3

> By Gauss's law, the amount of electric charge inside the volume enclosed by the surface is related to the integral of the electric field over a closed surface.

Which form is more safer to be said? 
Is there something more explicit?

Comment: In electro-statics (no moving charges), charges only create static electric fields. Where does your definition come from? In wikipedia it stated the "net electric flux ..."

Comment: It is about Gas Electron Multipliers where electrons are moving. There is a continuous flow of fill gas which is ionized so no particles created/destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

Gauss's law relates the integral of the electric field over a closed surface with the amount of charge inside the volume enclosed by this surface. It does not state anything about magnetic fields or about changes in time. So unfortunately I would not consider either to be 'safe'.

Comment: My new proposal: *By Gauss's law, the amount of electric charge inside the volume enclosed by the surface is related to the integral of the electric field over a closed surface.* What do you think?